# Microsoft Graph: Current authenticated context is not valid for this request

Tags: error-handling, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, adal

I had an app that used MSAL and the v2.0 endpoint to sign in users and get token.

I recently changed it to ADAL and the normal AAD endpoint (also changing the app), and now when I try to use the GraphService I get the following error: `Current authenticated context is not valid for this request`

- My user is admin
- All permissions have been delegated
- The token is successfully retrieved

Here is the code I use:

```
public static GraphServiceClient GetAuthenticatedClient()
        {
            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                    async (requestMessage) =>
                    {
                        string accessToken = await SampleAuthProvider.Instance.GetUserAccessTokenAsync();

                        // Append the access token to the request.
                        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);
                    }));
            return graphClient;
        }
```

Calling the method, where the actual error happens:

```
try
            {
                // Initialize the GraphServiceClient.
                GraphServiceClient graphClient = SDKHelper.GetAuthenticatedClient();

                // Get events.
                items = await eventsService.GetMyEvents(graphClient);
            }
            catch (ServiceException se)
            {

            }
```

Getting the token:

```
public async Task<string> GetTokenAsync()
        {
            ClientCredential cc = new ClientCredential(appId, appSecret);
            AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant.onmicrosoft.com");
            AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com", cc);

            return result.AccessToken;
        }
```

Can't find anything on this online so I am not sure how to continue.

Error:
[image]

Comment: I think that "bearer" needs to be "Bearer". I'm not sure that it is case-insensitive.

Comment: @RasmusW Should not be, since it works using MSAL with "bearer"

Comment: Please share the error body which contains request-id and timestamp to help debug.

Comment: Can you share the code that actually triggers the error?

Comment: @SriramDhanasekaran-MSFT I added more information to the question. I think it might be stemming from where I get the token, it does not feel right to use ClienCredential to get token of a signed in user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This exception is caused by the token acquired using the client credentials flow. In this flow, there is no context for **Me**.

To fix this issue, you need to specify the whose event you want to get. Or you need to provide the delegate-token.

code for your reference:

```
//var envens=await graphClient.Me.Events.Request().GetAsync();
var envens = await graphClient.Users["xxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com"].Events.Request().GetAsync();
```

Comment: How to provide delegate token?

Comment: The delegate-token is need to users interactive to enter their username and password. For example, we can use the **Authorization Code Grant  flow ** to get the delegate-token( refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code) for this flow).

Comment: Do you happen to know how to do it with python?