# Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException' Code: BadRequest Message: Current authenticated context is not valid for this request

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I'm having trouble when using the Microsoft Graph API. Whenever I try to get a calendar, I get the following error message:

> Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException' in
>   System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 'Code: BadRequest Message: Current
>   authenticated context is not valid for this request

At first, I thought it was similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42090125/microsoft-graph-current-authenticated-context-is-not-valid-for-this-request) post, but my user is authenticated, so I believe it's not the case.

Here's my code:

`EventController.cs`

```cs
public async Task<Calendar> GetEventInfoAsync()
    {
        var accessToken = await getAcessTokenAsync();
        DelegateAuthenticationProvider delegateAuthenticationProvider = new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
            (requestMessage) => 
            {
                requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        );
        GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(delegateAuthenticationProvider);
        var calendar = await graphClient.Me.Calendar.Request().GetAsync();
        return calendar;
    }
```

And this is how I get the access token:

```cs
public async Task<string> getAcessTokenAsync()
    {
        if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var userId = User.FindFirst("MicrosoftUserId")?.Value;
            ConfidentialClientApplication cca =
                new ConfidentialClientApplication( Configuration["MicrosoftAuth:ClientId"],
                                                    String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}{1}", "common", "/v2.0"),
                                                    Configuration["MicrosoftAuth:RedirectUri"]+ "signin-oidc", 
                                                    new Microsoft.Identity.Client.ClientCredential(Configuration["MicrosoftAuth:ClientSecret"]),
                                                    new SessionTokenCache(userId,_memoryCache).GetCacheInstance(),
                                                    null);               
            var token = await cca.AcquireTokenForClientAsync(new string[]{"https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"});
            return token.AccessToken;
        }
        else
            throw new Exception("User is not autenticated");
    }
```

Finally, this is how the authentication options look in the startup file.

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddOpenIdConnect(openIdOptions => 
        {
            openIdOptions.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
            openIdOptions.Authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}{1}", "common", "/v2.0");
            openIdOptions.ClientId = Configuration["MicrosoftAuth:ClientId"];
            openIdOptions.ClientSecret = Configuration["MicrosoftAuth:ClientSecret"];
            openIdOptions.SaveTokens = true;
            openIdOptions.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters{
                ValidateIssuer = false
            };
            var scopes = Configuration["MicrosoftAuth:Scopes"].Split(' ');
                foreach (string scope in scopes){
                    openIdOptions.Scope.Add(scope);
            }
            openIdOptions.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents{
                OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = async (context) =>
                {   
                    var userId = context.Principal.Claims.First(item => item.Type == ObjectIdentifierType).Value;
                    IMemoryCache memoryCache = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IMemoryCache>();
                    ConfidentialClientApplication cca =
                        new ConfidentialClientApplication( Configuration["MicrosoftAuth:ClientId"],
                                                            String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}{1}{2}", "common", "/v2.0", "/adminconsent"),
                                                            Configuration["MicrosoftAuth:RedirectUri"]+ "signin-oidc", 
                                                            new Microsoft.Identity.Client.ClientCredential(Configuration["MicrosoftAuth:ClientSecret"]),
                                                            new SessionTokenCache(userId,memoryCache).GetCacheInstance(),
                                                            null);
                    var code = context.ProtocolMessage.Code;                        
                    var result = await cca.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code,new string[]{"User.Read.All", "Calendars.ReadWrite"});
                    context.HandleCodeRedemption(result.AccessToken, result.IdToken);
                },
            };
        });
```

My app is registered in the Microsoft Application Registration Portal, and I do get a token when I request for it, so I'm not sure what could possibly be causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue with the previews thread. There are two kinds of token issued by Azure AD, delegate for use or app. The token you were acquire is using the **client credentials** flow which is delegate for app. There is no `me` context when you request using this kind of token(refer [Get access on behalf of a user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_user) and [Get access without a user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service) for the difference).

To integrate Microsoft Graph with web app and delegate the user to call the Microsoft Graph, you need to use the **code grant flow**(`OnAuthorizationCodeReceived` event) as you config in the `startup.cs` file.

Comment: I thought i was doing that. I've changed the Authority address to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/authorize?` in the openid options, and the authority address in the CCA for the `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived` event to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/token`, but I still get the same error message. When i changed the openId authority, i had to add the metadata address separately, as  `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration`

Comment: You're using `ConfidentialClientApplication` which is the Client Credentials flow. Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/guidedsetups/active-directory-windesktop for an example of using `PublicClientApplication`

Comment: Does it make sense to use OpenID connect With the PublicClientApplication? I think there is now method available to get the access token with the authorization code. Or should i use another type of OpenId Event?

Comment: I'm having trouble implementing the PublicClientApplication. I don't really understand how to set it up. In the example, it's implemented in a Desktop app but i'm not really sure how to use it on my MVC project.

Comment: @MarcosTrucco Please refer the [this code sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-v2) which demonstrate to integrate Azure AD V2.0 endpoint with web app. And please feel free to let me know if you still have the problem.