# Microsoft Graph api invalid scope

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

I'm using Java libraries of Microsoft Graph in my Java project. My code is as follows:

```
    String clientId = "my client id";
    List<String> scopes = Arrays.asList("https://graph.microsoft.com/calendars.read");
    String clientSecret = "my client secret";
    String tenant = "my tenant id";
    NationalCloud nationalCloud = NationalCloud.Global;

    ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(
            clientId,
            scopes,
            clientSecret,
            tenant,
            nationalCloud);

    IGraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider( authProvider ).buildClient();

    Calendar calendar = graphClient.me().calendar()
        .buildRequest()
        .get();
```

Permissions snapshot from portal.azure.com:
[image]

When I run the code, get following error:

```
OAuthProblemException{error='invalid_scope', description='AADSTS70011: The provided request must include a 'scope' input parameter. The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope https://graph.microsoft.com/calendars.read is not valid.
Trace ID: f5962e73-9665-4967-9aa5-4993a6698f00
Correlation ID: 3fc539c4-f62f-4858-b2f6-cb4e1d6c6a3a
Timestamp: 2020-05-07 11:44:29Z', uri='null', state='null', scope='null', redirectUri='null', responseStatus=0, parameters={}}
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.common.exception.OAuthProblemException.error(OAuthProblemException.java:59)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.validator.OAuthClientValidator.validateErrorResponse(OAuthClientValidator.java:63)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.validator.OAuthClientValidator.validate(OAuthClientValidator.java:48)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.response.OAuthClientResponse.validate(OAuthClientResponse.java:64)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.response.OAuthClientResponse.init(OAuthClientResponse.java:59)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.response.OAuthAccessTokenResponse.init(OAuthAccessTokenResponse.java:52)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.response.OAuthClientResponseFactory.createCustomResponse(OAuthClientResponseFactory.java:60)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.URLConnectionClient.execute(URLConnectionClient.java:111)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.OAuthClient.accessToken(OAuthClient.java:65)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.OAuthClient.accessToken(OAuthClient.java:55)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.OAuthClient.accessToken(OAuthClient.java:71)
    at com.microsoft.graph.auth.confidentialClient.ClientCredentialProvider.getAccessTokenNewRequest(ClientCredentialProvider.java:102)
    at com.microsoft.graph.auth.confidentialClient.ClientCredentialProvider.getAcccessToken(ClientCredentialProvider.java:67)
    at com.microsoft.graph.auth.confidentialClient.ClientCredentialProvider.authenticateRequest(ClientCredentialProvider.java:49)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.sendRequestInternal(CoreHttpProvider.java:232)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.send(CoreHttpProvider.java:204)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.send(CoreHttpProvider.java:184)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.BaseRequest.send(BaseRequest.java:306)
    at com.microsoft.graph.requests.extensions.CalendarRequest.get(CalendarRequest.java:52)
    at cmm_tests.MSGraph.main(MSGraph.java:55)
```

I've installed following maven dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
        <artifactId>microsoft-graph-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>microsoft-graph-auth-jar</groupId>
        <artifactId>microsoft-graph-auth-jar</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
        <artifactId>microsoft-graph</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I had to manually download jar of microsoft-graph-auth and install it using mvn install:install-file

Why could I be getting "invalid scope" error?

Is it because of "Delegated" permissions?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not because of "Delegated" permissions.

You are using  [ClientCredentialProvider](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-auth#b-client-credential-provider) and this provider sets `grant_type=client_credentials` in the login url. It will only use `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` as its scope.

you need to use `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` for the scope to fix your issue. It will give you the permission defined in your app.

Comment: Hi. When I use .default scope, I get the error: `Bad Request: Current authenticated context is not valid for this request. This occurs when a request is made to an endpoint that requires user sign-in. For example, /me requires a signed-in user.  Acquire a token on behalf of a user to make requests to these endpoints.  Use the OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow for mobile and native apps and the OAuth 2.0 implicit flow for single-page web apps.`

Comment: So how should I fetch the calendar? Can you show the code if 'me' is removed?

Comment: This is a different issue. In the client credentials flow, there is no context for Me .You are using 'me' i.e.,  Calendar calendar = graphClient.`me()`.calendar()...Please go through this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42090125/microsoft-graph-current-authenticated-context-is-not-valid-for-this-request
) which will help you in fixing your issue.